# ETL Script to dynamically map multiple EXECUTE SQL resultset to multiple tables (table name based on sql file provided)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transformation, etl, business-intelligence

ETL Script to dynamically map multiple execute sql resultset to multiple tables (table name based on sql file provided)

I have a source folder with sql files ( I can put it up as stored procedures as well ) . I know how to loop and execute sql tasks in a foreach container. Now the part where I'm stuck is I need to use the final result set of each sql queries and shove it into a table with the same name as the sql file.

So, Folder -> script1.sql , script2.sql etc -> ETL -> goes to table script1, table script2 etc.

EDIT : Based on the comment made by Joe, I just want to say that I'm aware of using insert within a script but I need to insert it onto a table in a different server.And Linked servers are not the ideal solutions

Any psuedocode or link to tutorials will be extremely helpful . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would add the table creation to the script.  It is probably the simplest way to do this.  If your script is `Select SomeField From Table1`, you could change it to `Select SomeField Into Table script1 From Table1`.  Then there is no need to map in SSIS which is not easy to do from my experience.

Comment: -Joe C . I want to use it because I need it inserted to a table residing on a different server. I don't want to use a linked server. That will slow the process down!

Comment: I never seen a linked server to transfer data slower than SSIS can.  It is usually a security concern that prevents me from using linked servers.  In any case, if you want to dynamically map columns it will not be simple but you can find a number of related questions here on SO.